# Error when saving json to database mysql?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $image = ['http://localhost.loca/image/product/01-1627140249.jpg', 'http://localhost.loca/image/product/03-169983334.jpg'];
  $product = new Product();
  $product->image = json_encode($image);
  $product->save();
}
```

And the results are stored in the database

```
["http:\/\/localhost.loca\/image\/product\/01-1627140249.jpg","http:\/\/localhost.loca\/image\/product\/03-169983334.jpg"]
```

There are `\` being generated. is there any fix. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. Because this is an error in the json format saved in the database

Answer (score 0):

I use : `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` fixed the problem!

`json_encode($image, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)`